# how to change xml by browser

Tags: xml, xslt, browser, comments, conditional-statements

I would like to change some rules in my XML depending on the browser. For example, the 'fontcolor' should be black when using IE. So far I googled it, I found this could be possible using XSLT. But unfortunately, after googling/trying&error after 1/2 days, I still didn't get the clue how to do this.

Could someone help me how to solve this? Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks !!

EetieD.

My current XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>
<skin version='1.1' name='player' author='me'>
    <components>
        <component name='control'>
            <settings>
                <setting name='fontsize' value='10' />
                <setting name='fontcolor' value='0xffffff' /> <!-- if IE: 0x000000-->
                //.....
```

My current XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<!-- .... -->
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:comment>
    <![CDATA[[if !IE]>show non-iE text<![endif]]]>
  </xsl:comment>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a good way to detect browsers using only XSLT. Although XSLT was originally designed to be executed on XML in-browser, that's not how it worked out in practice. I think you'll be better off doing your browser detection [in Javascript](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html).

From there, you could conditionally output the XML you want directly from the JavaScript, or you could pass the browser type as an external variable to your XSLT and let it handle the conditional logic.