# XML containing SVG and VML based on the browser

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, xml-parsing, fusioncharts

I am using Fusion Chart with "PURE JAVASCRIPT" but with the export feature we want at client side.so FusionChart gives SVG or VML of the chart at client side.we want to merge this VML or SVG to XML file with the XSLT stylesheet.so as of now we want to give export to XML feature into our application.

now the problem is SVG only understood by Mozilla ,chrome and for IE it gives VML. so client will get common file containing both SVG and VML but the problem is there is no meant in XSLT to detect the browser type and version.i have used IE conditional comment but it don't work in chrome,mozilla and the  does not work in IE.Even with javascript doesnot work for that i will be wanting javascript variable value in XSLT variable which will not be feasible as XML renders first before javascript so i am not able to have the common XML+XSLT code for all browser.as we want to give stand alone XML to the client containing data + image.

any help regarding this will be appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="#stylesheet"?>
<!DOCTYPE doc [
<!ATTLIST xsl:stylesheet id ID #REQUIRED>]>
<doc>
<xsl:stylesheet id="stylesheet" version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:template match="xsl:stylesheet" />
 <xsl:template match="/doc">
<html>
<head>
 <style>
  body{
  font-family: Arial, Verdana,Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }
  table{
  font-size: 11px;
  }
 th{
 background-color:#D1D2D4;
 }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<br />
   <!-- detect browser here for getting SVG or VML if Mozilla,chrome then SVG->

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"........> </svg>

 <!-- If IE <=8 then VML -->

 <br/>
 <table border="2" cellspacing="1" width="86%">
  <tr>
   <th>Category</th>
   <th>Hits</th>
   <th>Bytes</th>
   </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>IPAddress</td>
   <td>1818</td>
   <td>747.32 MB</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>None</td>
   <td>1523</td>
   <td>27.82 MB</td>
   </tr>
 </table>
  </body>
 </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
 </doc>
```

Thanks,
Asha Koshti

Comment: Maybe provide both SVG and VML in XML, whatever is supported, will be rendered. There isn't any sane browser that supports both in standard mode!

Comment: ShamasisBhattacharya  ..i dont want the both but want something with that i can check the browser type so can render one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can always get the SVG  as string (in IE6+ or any browser) using the API - `chart.getSVGString()`. Will that help?

Comment: yep..i can get the SVG but that SVG + other data are combined and put into XML for giving to the client,now if client opens that file in IE6 or IE7 then it will not be able to render the SVG contents at all.so for that reason i want condition to check whether to render SVG or VML

Comment: You can not detect browser using XSLT - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274529/how-to-change-xml-by-browser. You can however check this in JavaScript itself. I am not sure how are you building the XSLT. If you can share the code or scaled-down code, I can try helping.

Comment: i have included example above so if you can help me than it will be good.